# How to parse this JSON with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a PHP Sage that return this message:

```
{"username":"andrefilipem", "location":"", "event":"0", "date":"2020-04-25 19:20:05", "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce at lacinia nunc. Sed mi sapien, accumsan quis justo ut, tincidunt blandit metus. Donec efficitur sagittis nisi. Nam nunc nisl, iaculis at nibh id, molestie iaculis massa. Donec cursus, massa id eleifend pharetra, mi ex hendrerit ante, a vulputate nunc felis elementum neque. Phasellus commodo libero nisi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi eget velit iaculis, tempus nunc et, imperdiet justo. Pellentesque nulla nisi, semper at mauris a, malesuada sollicitudin eros. Sed scelerisque purus at augue iaculis, in ultricies elit dapibus. Ut maximus ex eget egestas scelerisque. Donec commodo turpis quis neque efficitur lacinia. Nunc quis cursus velit. Quisque et velit eleifend quam tristique scelerisque a quis dui. Aliquam id dui id felis auctor ultricies at vitae enim. Cras ipsum justo, pulvinar non lacus tristique, bibendum ultricies lorem. Mauris a efficitur nunc, ac volutpat elit. Sed blandit arcu non consequat tincidunt. Fusce ac euismod risus. Quisque vel nisi porta mi auctor pharetra et nec diam. Donec nulla lectus, rutrum sit amet laoreet eu, commodo blandit ex. Nam ut justo neque. Cras porttitor sit amet ex at fringilla. Duis mauris turpis, tincidunt eu pulvinar porta, ultrices vel ligula. Mauris vel rhoncus sem. Nulla eu semper ex. Suspendisse aliquet augue arcu, quis lobortis metus tincidunt quis. Sed id convallis felis. Cras molestie mi ex, vel maximus odio tristique eu. Nam quis purus ut diam varius tincidunt id at quam. Praesent dapibus ultrices tortor, a hendrerit turpis commodo quis. Pellentesque iaculis tellus. Além de que adoro comida chinesa "}
```

My problem is when I run JSON message in http://json.parser.online.fr there is no error, but when I try to convert this text message intro JS object there is an "JSON Parse error: Unterminated string" error.

Here is my JS code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: EndSer+"includes/getPostInfo.php?username="+localStorage.getItem("usernameWI")+"&password="+localStorage.getItem("passwordWI")+"&postCod="+postCod,
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    success: function (msg) {
        msg=JSON.parse(msg);
        alert(msg.username);
    },
    cache: false,
    processData: false
})
```

Comment: Then the response is not what you think it is. Check it in the network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: Check what you're actually getting. Either in the Network tab or log the contents of `msg`. [This is valid JSON](https://jsbin.com/zohuhek/edit?js,console)

Comment: add `console.log(msg);` just before `msg=JSON.parse(msg);` to see what `msg` contains

Comment: @Andreas Please check your response in network tab. Here is the same problem. You can look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656389/json-parse-error-unterminated-string

Comment: Thank you for your comments but the network tab shows the same. And console.log(msg) too.

Comment: I realized my problem was the existence of newlines on the message that do not appear on php page. Thank you

Comment: Don't built your own JSON...